# How to force TADOConnection to throw an exception when an SQL error happens after a returned result set

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ado

TADOConnection does not want to throw an exception when exception occurs after some result set has been returned. For example:

```
ADOConnection1.Execute('SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT 0; THROW 50000, ''Custom error'', 1;');
```

The above code won't throw because there is a result set caused by `SELECT 0;`

How to force TADOConnection to throw an exception in such case? I can't avoid having a result set returned. Things I've tried:

- Handling `OnInfoMessage` event, but it never gets fired.
- Checking TADOConnection.Errors property, but there are no errors there.

I've found an article that targets this issue, but it concerns .NET:

[The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](http://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the `Custom Error` to show, using a `TADOQuery` like this:

```
var
  t : integer;
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT 0; THROW 50000, ''Custom error'', 1;';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  t := 0;
  ADOQuery1.NextRecordset(t); // exception thrown here
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am having problem if there is no result set returned. ADOQuery1.Open won't work in such case. I guess there is no universal way to handle both cases. Will accept this answer if no more answers appear.

Comment: Well its not the best solution maybe, but if you know each time when you write the query if it can return a resultset or not, you could choose to use ADOQuery or not. Unfortunate it is off course not possible to do `NextRecordSet` on a closed ADOQuery

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but how about always add `select 0` to the queries ?

Comment: I think you should use TADOCommand for statements that don't return a result set. I hope you have some control over what kind of statement is executed, so you can actually decide which component to use.

Comment: @GuidoG Not stupid at all, I've used it where I could :)